# MySQL Table Locks with Transactions

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I want to know that is there any way to lock MySQL tables without committing transaction implicitly.

Suppose I have two tables (table_1, table_2) and I insert data in to these tables at the same time with transactions. And I need to lock 'table_2' so that other users cannot write/modify 'table_2' until the transaction is completed. My problem is When I lock table_2 the transaction is committed implicitly. Yes I know it's explained in MySQL documentation

> LOCK TABLES is not transaction-safe and implicitly commits any active
>   transaction before attempting to lock the tables

I want to know that is there any other transaction safe method to do table locking.

Here is my C# code segment

```
MySQLTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();
command.Transaction = trans;
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('val1', 'val2')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "LOCK TABLES table_2 WRITE";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES ('val1', 'val2')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "RELEASE TABLES";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

trans.Commit();
```

Any idea to lock and insert data to 'table_2' without committing transaction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What storage engine do your tables use?  If they are using a transactional engine (such as InnoDB), then you shouldn't need to explicitly lock your tables: merely performing the insertion operations within a transaction (as you are doing) should ensure that they are isolated from concurrent sessions.  What is the actual problem that you are facing?

Comment: Yes it is InnoDB. I want to make sure that no one can read/modify table_2 until the transaction is completed. If some user access 'table_2' before transaction is completed it will be a problem to accuracy.

Comment: No, it won't.  The *whole point* of encapsulating your operations within a transaction is to isolate them from concurrent sessions: the insertions will become visible, atomically, to other sessions only when you commit your transaction - until then, they are only visible within the transaction itself.  Simply remove your `LOCK TABLES` and `RELEASE TABLES` commands.

Comment: Do I need to use any isolation level for the transaction?

Comment: All transactions use an isolation level.  The level that is chosen only affects what changes from outside the transaction are seen from within it; thus you may wish to select an appropriate isolation level for your other transactions - the default level, `REPEATABLE_READ`, should suffice for most use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intent on locking the proper way to achieve this to your original intention, lock both tables up front:

```
LOCK TABLES table_1 WRITE, table_2 WRITE
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
UNLOCK TABLES
```

Native MySQL provides this (although I never tested if it will work via the connector - but don't see why not.)

Once you have the locks no one can get in between.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, written in C#

```
using (var con = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = "YourConnectionString" })
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction();
            MySqlCommand command = con.CreateCommand();
            try
            {
                command.CommandText = @"LOCK TABLES table_1 WRITE, table_2 WRITE;
                                        INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
                                        INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
                                        UNLOCK TABLES;";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                trans.Rollback();
                conn.msgErr(ex.Message + " sql query error.");
                conn.msgErr("Neither record was written to database.");
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Dispose();
                trans.Dispose();
            }

        }
```